# Overwrite template without the "name" attribute

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How can I overwrite the template of something like `select.phtml`

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
</block>
```

via my module, even tough it does not have a "name" attribute only a class and "as"?

I tried the following:

**MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.options">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="MyCompany_MyModule::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

but that does not work at all.

Comment: Have you tried targeting it with the alias? The name attribute is not required in Magento 2 so this happens in quite a few places.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Check the accepted answer here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86188/magento-2-changing-a-blocks-template.

Comment: In the accepted answer does not work here, because it references the block by the "name" attribute. <referenceBlock name="block_to_change">

Comment: Yeah I was 50/50 on whether it would work. If you only want to change the markup you could just overwrite the template, you wouldn't even need to know the name for that - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html

Comment: you can remove the referenceContainer wrapper as the references are unique in the whole layout. It is not possible to override a block without a name via layout.xml, since a random name is created. It might be possible to add a Plugin though where the blocks are created, then looking for the template string and replace it

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to do this so I thought I would share my solution for overriding a template file for a block without a name only alias. I will walk through the entire solution in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution.

Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Module',
__DIR__
);
```

Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::product/view/options/type/select.phtml';
}
```

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type/select.phtml

Make the changes you are needing in the phtml file. That should be it!

Enable the module, setup:upgrade, compile, deploy static content, clear cache, etc and you will see the changes.