# How to override a block without name?

Tags: magento2, layout, bundled-product, creditmemo

I am trying to override following file

> module-bundle/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_items">
            <block class="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" as="bundle" template="sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I override it by creating same name layout file in my module

> Vendor_App/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
    <block class="Vendor\App\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" as="bundle" template="Vendor_App::sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

But my class and template are not overridden. I have created the class and phtml in my module.

I tried to override it using di.xml by adding following code.

```
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" type="Vendor\App\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer"/>
```

And this works, but the problem is, on clicking Update Qty's button, it  fetches my template instead of its own template as the layout for Update Qty is different.

I tried above thing with Configurable and simple product both works perfectly, only bundle type is creating issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setChild()` to replace a block by its alias. First create the new block with a name, then call `setChild()` via `<action>`:

```
<referenceBlock name="order_items">
    <block class="Vendor\App\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Items\Renderer" name="custom_renderer" template="Vendor_App::sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml"/>

    <action method="setChild">
        <argument name="alias" xsi:type="string">bundle</argument>
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">custom_renderer</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian for a reply, but after going with your answer I'm getting following error `1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentoce21/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php on line 472`

Comment: @Nausif I forgot `xsi:type="string"` in the `argument` nodes, that might be the problem

Comment: @FabianSchmengler will this work with `<arguments>` instead of `<action>`? As [`<action>` has been deprecated](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_act).

Comment: @BenCrook I don't think so, but I'm not sure, did not look into the inner workins of `<arguments>` yet.

Comment: It does not work, I am trying to override cart item deafult template. "checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/239387/14403

I believe that is the same solution you are looking for.