# How do I reference a block that only has an alias, and no name in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides

I am attempting to modify some arguments for a block that is defined in `module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` on line 41.

`<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">`

The problem, is that the block is not defined with a name, it only has an alias, so I am unable to use something like `<referenceBlock name="default"/>` to modify it.

I need to modify the "columns" argument inside this block.
Is there any other way to reference this block, or am I pretty much out of luck?

Comment: Take the exact reference from http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134802/magento-2-how-to-change-template-of-a-block-without-name/134865#134865

Answer (score 2):

You have to just override using below way,

**app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_order_view.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.status" template="order/order_status.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" name="order.date" template="order/order_date.phtml"/>
            <container name="order.actions.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="actions-toolbar order-actions-toolbar">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" cacheable="false"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="sales.order.info.buttons">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info\Buttons\Rss" as="buttons.rss" name="sales.order.info.buttons.rss" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="order.comments" template="order/order_comments.phtml" before="sales.order.info.links"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" name="sales.order.view" cacheable="false" after="sales.order.info.links">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" name="order_items" template="order/items.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="2" class="mark"</argument>
                            <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="order/tax.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="info" name="sales.order.info" after="sales.order.view"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can change `colspan` in above file.

Comment: Surely there has to be a better way than copying the full file

Comment: @BenCrook Not to mention, this does not help if a module wants to modify that template. The solution only works if done in a theme. There's a nasty hack here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157608

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but it works as long as you are using simple type products. I think magento left this part unfinished. Also 'discont' is misspelled there(kinda funny):

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" name="simple" as="simple" template="order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                    <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                    <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                    <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                    <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                    <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                    <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                    <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                    <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                    <item name="action" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-action</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```